# Why does this assertion have this word order?

Tags: word-order

> »Er ist nicht klug genug.«
> »**Ist er wohl.** Mein Vater weiß so viel wie sie.«

"Ist er wohl" puts the verb in first position but is not a question. What is the grammatical basis for doing this?

Comment: It's a V1 sentence (Stirnsatz). Quite common with "doch" ("wohl" is a synonym). I think these are called exclamative sentences.

Comment: Recommended read: [Vorfeld-Analepse bei Aussagen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1999). (My tl;dr in English [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54334/35111))..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) of: "**Das** ist er wohl."